# Can I shorten this ternary statement?

Tags: javascript

Here is a line with a ternary statement, can it be shortened?

```
var something = siteState === null ? undefined : siteState
```

Comment: A minifier will do the shortening for the production code, don't minify your developement code.

Comment: Is there a particular need for this? `null` and `undefined` are interchangeable in most cases anyway.

Comment: something related to the ternary operator. Something that returns the value siteState without saying  " : siteState"

Comment: `something = siteState || undefined` will set it to `undefined` if it would otherwise be a falsy value.

Comment: Not if you need to explicitly differentiate between null and undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways:

```
var something = siteState || undefined;
```

This will also turn `false`, `0`, etc into `undefined`.

```
function nullToUndefined(v) {
    return v === null ? undefined : v;
}
bar something = nullToUndefined(siteState);
```

Comment: Is this language dependant or will all language treat this the same?

Comment: @akaBase The first answer only works in languages with a special `||` operator. In most languages, it returns a boolean. In JavaScript, it returns the left side if its truthy.

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks but not sure what you mean by special `||` (or)? all langaugaes Ive used it has been treated the same, (js,php,c#)

Comment: @akaBase For example in PHP: `2 || 1 === true`. In JavaScript: `2 || 1 === 2`.

Comment: @Anonymous thanks, using the explicit nature of it.

Comment: @akaBase: Wrt the Boolean OR operator, languages my differ in two main ways: whether they allow non-boolean arguments and perform type coercion. If they do, whether the return value is a Boolean value or one of its operands.